# Not getting the user info in azure-ad

Tags: node.js, azure, express, passport.js, azure-ad-msal

I want to authenticate user using azure-ad strategy in nodejs using passportjs library.

I have created the methods according to the passportjs docs for OIDCStrategy:

```
passport.use(
    new OIDCStrategy(
        {
            clientID: config.passport.azure.clientID,
            clientSecret: config.passport.azure.clientSecret,
            passReqToCallback: true,
            redirectUrl: `${config.url}/v1/user/login/azure/callback`,
            responseType: 'code',
            allowHttpForRedirectUrl: true,
            responseMode: 'query',
            scope: ['profile', 'email', 'offline_access'],
            loggingLevel: 'error',
            identityMetadata: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${config.passport.azure.tenantID}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`,
        },
        async (req, iss, sub, profile, jwtClaims, access_token, refresh_token, params, done) => {
            try {
                console.log({ profile });

                return done(null, profile);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
    )
);
```

Here is the code of redirectUrl endpoint:

```
router.route('/login/azure').get(passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect'));
router.route('/login/azure/callback').get(
    passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', {
        failureRedirect: '/v1/hello',
        successRedirect: '/v1/user/login',
    })
);
```

I have initialized the passport and set the session as well.

After the auth I am being redirected to this endpoint: `/v1/user/login/azure/callback`
And after that I am getting redirected to the `/v1/hello` endpoint which is failure redirect. I am also not getting the user's info at this endpoint `/v1/user/login/azure/callback`